# How to solve an application-defined or object-define error?

Tags: vba

The error says "Application-defined or object-defined error." It stops on the line where it has `filename = Sheet3.Cells(i,4)` Please help with this one. Thanks

Alright I updated the code already. I removed the x variable with my intended one which is `i`.

```
Sub sendMails()

Dim ol As Outlook.Application
Dim olmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim sig As String
Dim filename As String
Dim outlookapp As Object
Dim outlookmailitem As Object
Dim attachment As Object
Dim path As String

Set ol = New Outlook.Application

path = "C:\Statements\"

For i = 2 To Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
filename = Sheet3.Cells(i, 4)
attachment = path + filename

    Set olmail = ol.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With olmail
        .To = Sheet3.Cells(i, 1).Value
        .Subject = Sheet3.Cells(i, 2).Value
        .Body = Sheet3.Cells(i, 3).Value
        .Add (attachment)
        .Display

    End With
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: what is the `x`?

Comment: right. that is one of the errors. and now it says, there is an error on the next line that says, "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing that out. I still have to really learn a lot here.

Comment: You should change tag from `vb.net` to `vba` though.

Comment: I dont see where you are defining what the `Sheet3` variable is... is that the name of the sheet? in that case, it would be `Worksheets("Sheet3")` or if it's the 3rd sheet, it would be `WorkSheets(3)` - without you showing what it is, it's difficult to know what you are trying to do.

Comment: @braX `Sheet3` is a worksheet `Codename`.  It doesn't need to be defined as long as the sheet exists and hasn't been renamed in the VBA editor.  That said, we can't rule out the possibility that x is defined somewhere as an object. This question needs to be improved.

Comment: Start by putting [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) at the top of each module. 
It enforces variable declaration and reports undeclared or misspelled variables/constants at compile time. 
To have this automatically in new modules, set the [Require Variable Declaration](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/options/index.html) option in the VBA Editor. 
This is really a must have for VBA development.

Comment: `attachment` is declared as `Object`. In line 5 you attempt to assign string to an object. This is does not make sense. You should declare `attachment` as `String`.